# ActionScript 3: Adding eventListener to a child with For loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, parent-child, addition, event-listener

I get error code 1009 when I run this code...

```
for(var aObj:int = 1; aObj < 50; aObj++){           
    this["elementsSb.netDev"+aObj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
    this["elementsSb.netDev"+aObj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
}
```

But when I run basically in this way...

```
elementsSb.netDev1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
elementsSb.netDev1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragObject);
```

It works. Though, I don't want to make it this way because it's a bit messy, and I have 49 netDev objects.

Any proper way to deal with this guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this["elementsSb.netDev"+aObj] -> this["elementsSb"]["netDev"+aObj]

Comment: @fsbmain, you should add that as an answer, as probably that's the reason of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the fences to access to the properties of any objects the dot `.` withing the string identifier doesn't work.

The correct path must be:

```
this["elementsSb"]["netDev"+aObj]
```